# Revert system feature split-screen

Tags: multi-window

I have official Android 9.0 ROM for HU PX5 GS rk3368.
However, I think is more like general question.

In my system, split-screen feature is disable (or just some apps are missing).
I tried to set `enable_freeform_support 1` but that did not helped.
Note I did it by:

```
adb settings put global enable_freeform_support 1
```

That is because Developer Options are also disabled (I can not enter - probably app / Activity removed)

I'm pretty sure there is a way to fix that, but I don't have enough knowledge about Android to figure it out.
I have access to root (over adb)

**EDIT 1**
After executing command and rebooting I checked if it was not reset to previous value
`settings get global enable_freefrom_support`
It returns 1 so it is ok. However feature is still not working.

I also find out that following prop may disable spliting screen
`getprop ro.config.low_ram`
But it is not present in my configuration.

Comment: When you run the command, do you get an error message? If not run the command again, then reboot the device and check if the feature is enabled.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I have updated question